# low-level caching key in rails. Built-in?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching

I'm reading the docs for Caching with Rails and I came across this:

> Consider the following example. An application has a Product model
>   with an instance method that looks up the product’s price on a
>   competing website. The data returned by this method would be perfect
>   for low-level caching:
>
> class Product < ApplicationRecord

```
def competing_price
>     Rails.cache.fetch("#{cache_key}/competing_price", expires_in: 12.hours) do
>       Competitor::API.find_price(id)
>     end   end end
```

> Notice that in this example we used the cache_key method, so the 
>   cache-key will be something like
>   products/233-20140225082222765838000/competing_price. cache_key
>   generates a string based on the model’s id and updated_at attributes.
>   This is a common convention and has the benefit of invalidating the
>   cache whenever the product is updated. In general, when you use
>   low-level caching for instance level information, you need to generate
>   a cache key.

Do I need to build that cache_key method or is it built in? Would it just be something like this:

```
module ProductsHelper
  def cache_key_for_products
    count          = Product.count
    max_updated_at = Product.maximum(:updated_at).try(:utc).try(:to_s, :number)
    "products/all-#{count}-#{max_updated_at}"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to provide a cache-key and be able to reconstruct it if needing to invalidate the cache.

For example:

```
cache_key = "#{account.id}-#{user.id}-#{product.id}"
Rails.cache.fetch("#{cache_key}/competing_price", expires_in: 12.hours) do
    Competitor::API.find_price(id)
end
```

...

Later on if the product is sold out or removed, you can invalidate the cache via the same cache_key:

```
Rails.cache.delete(cache_key)
```